# Not Able to Target Closest img Element To File Input Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know why I am not able to target the closest image element to file input

```js
$('.file').on('change', function(ev) {
   var f = ev.target.files[0];
   var fr = new FileReader();
   fr.onload = function(ev2) {
     $(this).closest('.img').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
     $(this).find('.img').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
     $(this).next('.img').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
   };
   fr.readAsDataURL(f);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" class="file" name="image" />
<img class="img" />
<input type="file" class="file" name="image" />
<img class="img" />
```

As you can see I already tried

```
 $(this).closest('.img').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
 $(this).find('.img').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
 $(this).next('.img').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
```

but it is not doing the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to find img closest to the input file which changes, so you must use `ev.target` because inside the second function scope changes and this does not refer to file input anymore, something like this seems to work:

```js
$('.file').on('change', function(ev) {
   var f = ev.target.files[0];
   var fr = new FileReader();
   fr.onload = function(ev2) {
     $(ev.target).next('.img').attr('src', ev2.target.result);
   };
   fr.readAsDataURL(f);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" class="file" name="image" />
<img class="img" />
<input type="file" class="file" name="image" />
<img class="img" />
```